# Converting MYSQL time to PHP time

Tags: php, mysql, time

I have a column of type time in mysql database, I want to convert it to php time object to be able to use it in some functions, I've tried to use strtotime function but that dosen't work with me,
this is my php code:

```
$result=mysql_query("select time,name from users where user_id='1'");
if($result)
{
    $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$time=$row['time'];
    $formatted_time=strtotime($time);               
echo date('H:i:s',$formatted_time);     
}
```

but what I always get is:
`01:00:00`
I don't know where the 1 hour did come from!

I know this question may be duplicated but all of answers are talking about using strtotime function which didn't work as you see.
could you help pleas?

many thanx in advance

Comment: What does `var_dump($row['time']);` output?

Comment: Is this a legacy application? `mysql_query` shouldn't be used in new code because it's been deprecated, is dangerous if used incorrectly, and is being removed from future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). A guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) has a number of recommendations as to how to keep your application up-to-date.

Comment: is the "time" row an integer, a date or something else? I don't think that strtotime is the correct function to use.

Comment: Perhaps a Daylight Savings time error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For detail about "TIME_FORMAT"  [click here](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-time_format-function.php)

```
$result=mysql_query("select TIME_FORMAT(`time`, '%h:%i %p') as time, `name` from users where user_id='1'");
if ($result)
{
  $row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
  $time=$row['time'];
  echo $time;
}
```

Comment: @Zsigoveny, thanx very much guys and thanx for your detailed steps Pankaj Kumar Jha, that worked with me perfectly! except that I needed to convert the retrieved field using strtotim, actually I've tried using TIME_FORMAT befor asking my question but my problem was that I didn't use strtotime with the result so that I couldn't use it in my functions. but now, I'm facing a problem in inserting the result of my functions  which is in strtotime format into the TIME type column in my db :(, do you have any idea guys? , I've tried to use date('H:i:s',$result) but it doesn't work, any help? :(

Answer (score 2):

Use `TIME_FORMAT:`

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT('14:30:00', '%h:%i %p'); /* 02:30 PM */
```

TIME_FORMAT is a `mysql` function , you can use it within your query!